# How to run parallel stages in isolated pods for a declarative jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, parallel-testing, jenkins-kubernetes

I'm trying to run some *end-to-end* tests in parallel and on **DIFFERENT** kubernetes pods on a declarative jenkins pipeline, jenkins however seems to attempt running the parallel stages on the **SAME** kubernetes pod. This leads to **database deadlocks** since both processes try inserting/truncating/updating/querying the same tables. Is there a way I can spin up a different pod for each of the parallel stages?

**The kubernetes-plugin config:**

```
  agent {
  kubernetes {
    label 'my-label'
    defaultContainer 'jnlp'
    yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dind
spec:
  containers:
    - name: < default container >
      image: < image >
      securityContext:
          privileged: true
          fsGroup: 1000
      command:
      - cat
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
        - name: jenkins-bundle-gems
          mountPath: /usr/local/bundle


    - name: <tests-container-name>
      image: < image > 
      securityContext:
          privileged: true
          fsGroup: 1000
      volumeMounts:
        - name: jenkins-bundle-gems
          mountPath: /usr/local/bundle
      command:
      - cat
      tty: true
"""
 }
   }
```

**The parallel stage:**

```
      stage('Test'){
        parallel {
          stage("Branch 1") {
              steps {
                container('<tests-container-name>') {
                  sh "jenkins/scripts/initdb.sh"
                  sh 'bundle exec rspec --exclude-pattern "spec/features/*_spec.rb" spec'
                }
              }
            }
            stage("Branch 2") {
              steps {
                container('<tests-container-name>') {
                  sh "jenkins/scripts/initdb.sh"
                  sh "bundle exec rspec `jenkins/scripts/split_features.sh 0`"
                }
              }
            }
        }
      }
```

**EXPECTATION:** I would like for jenkins to spin up two different pods for each of the parallel stages. This would allow me to use different databases for each of the tests.

**ACTUAL RESULT:** Jenkins runs both stages concurrently on the same pod.

Comment: Hi Marc, you defined only one pod with 2 containers. According to your stage you are using that same container. I believe you should check the option for side car (or 2 side cars) also known as init containers to fullfill your needs

Comment: @Chen What if I defined 5 containers ( from the same image) on the same pod. Would that solve the concurrency issue?

Comment: I think you are missing the point. I suggest you should change the yaml file and the jenkinsfile. On the Jenkinsfile use different containers instead the same onr

Answer (score 3):

You have__________: `stage > parallel > stage > steps`.

You need to have also: `stage > parallel > stage > agent`.

Do not repeat pod definition twice, it is recommended to put the pod definition in a separated file and refer to it using `yamlFile` instead of `yaml` :

```
  stage('Test'){
    parallel {
      stage("Branch 1") {
          agent {
             kubernetes {
               defaultContainer 'jnlp'
               yamlFile 'Jenkins.pod.yaml'
             }
          }
          steps {
            container('<tests-container-name>') {
              sh "jenkins/scripts/initdb.sh"
              sh 'bundle exec rspec --exclude-pattern "spec/features/*_spec.rb" spec'
            }
          }
        }
        stage("Branch 2") {
          agent {
             kubernetes {
               defaultContainer 'jnlp'
               yamlFile 'jenkins.pod.yaml'
             }
          }
          steps {
            container('<tests-container-name>') {
              sh "jenkins/scripts/initdb.sh"
              sh "bundle exec rspec `jenkins/scripts/split_features.sh 0`"
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

**Hint**

if blueocean is one of your plugins, it will help you to draw your pipeline under `http://HOST/blue/organizations/jenkins/pipeline-editor/`, then you can copy the Jenkinsfile code by typing [Cmd + s]

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
stage("Run additional parallel tests") {
        parallel( 
            "parallel stage 1": {
                [INSERT YOUR CODE HERE]
            },

            "parallel stage 2": {
                [INSERT YOUR CODE HERE]
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `agent {}` for each parallel stage to launch a pod per stage.

Comment: please give a boilerplate like [George Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381198/747579) I have a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/abdennour/4a1c2ac93fbe7edc36768a5ae80a2671) to present all ways of parallelism